# Eclipse CDT forgets include paths

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I have  project in Eclipse that I created using an existing Makefile that specifies the `#include` paths for gcc.

I have noticed that, when I build the project, Eclipse resolves all the include directives correctly. However, if I close the project and I **re-open** it, Eclipse **forgets** how to resolve the `#include` directives (the include paths), and I need to re-build the project to have Eclipse resolve the inclusion paths again.

Why doesn't Eclipse save this information with the project?

This is all with Eclipse Juno on Linux.